# react-native init trowing errors

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to setup a `react-native` using `react-native init myProject` command.

But when I run the command I recive the following error:

```
Looks like you installed react-native globally, maybe you meant react-native-cli?
To fix the issue, run:
npm uninstall -g react-native
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

However I tried to uninstall react-native an reinstall react-native-cli but still does the same.

I'm doing something wrong?
Does anybody can explain me how to fix this?

Comment: react-native was installed globally, im stupid.